# CakePHP model and querying troubles

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I'm using CakePHP 2.3.8 and I'm having trouble getting Cake to properly search for a value. It appears not to be case sensitive. I'm searching for 'User.id' and the query result it shows up as 'user.id'

```
users table
id  |   username   | password  |  email   | created
```

I'm trying to find the date a user was created in my ReservationController

```
$this->loadmodel('User');
$date = $this->User->find('first',array(
                                    'conditions' => array(
                                        'User.id' => $id    //note: 'id' => $id gives the same results
                                     )
                          ));
```

I get the following error

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user.id' in 'where clause'
SQL Query: SELECT `User`.`created` FROM `TestDB`.`users` AS `User` WHERE `user`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
```

When I copy the query into PHPMyadmin and change 'user.id' to 'User.id' it then works. Why is Cake making the u lowercase even though I capitalize it in my query? If I change it to 'Users.id' cake will then search with an uppsercause U and adds the s, but that's not what I want.

I tried adding a primary key to my user model with `public $primaryKey = 'id';` but that didn't do anything. Currently, I don't have any references for primary key in my User model so I'm not sure where/why it's deciding to search for 'user.id' even though I specifically reference 'User.id' in my search. In fact, the only thing in my user model is for form validation.

Comment: Normally CakePHP should not modify the key, except for quoting it properly. First try to clear your cache (`/app/tmp/cache/`), this often fixes model/db/schema related problems. Have you tested it with a clean CakePHP installation and a dummy model, just to check whether it's a general problem? Also does the same happen with the latest 2.4.3?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to Add modelName in Query if its for Same Model.. [Retriving data](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-first)

```
$this->loadModel('User');
$date = $this->User->find('first',array(
                                    'conditions' => array(
                                        'id' => $id
                                     )
                          ));
```

Comment: That does not work and would not make a difference. That's the whole reason why I put 'User.id' in the first place. Referencing the modelName wouldn't hurt the query. If my models happened to be set up that with a hasMany relationship with another table that has the same column name (not id though), it would be necessary or else it would cause that column to be ambiguous. I wish that you guys on StackOverflow weren't like Reddit in the sense of being so quick to downvote anything